# An alien dances with woman on beach at night, then leaves. Years later the alien returns but she is dead, he takes the dog

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Most likely published in Asimov's or Fantasy & Science Fiction in the 80's or 90's. The woman lived alone in a cabin in the Northwest, I think, and went down to the beach when she saw the ship land there. She had a dog then. She dances with the alien, a humanoid with eyes like gold coins.

He leaves, years pass, dog dies and she gets another. She is ailing in her cabin. The alien returns, and she had just died. He leaves, and takes her dog with him.

I really liked that she was remembered by someone, and that her dog was not left alone.

Comment: Darn, I know I read this, but I don't recall the title either. I probably have it somewhere in my collection, so if I come across it again at some point, I'll report back.

Answer (score 5):

Could this be [Dance on a Forgotten Shore](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?49258), a novelette by Alan Dean Foster and Sally McBride?

> Sylvie abruptly realized she was still gripping her ax. Retreating a
> few  steps, she buried the blade harmlessly in a log, returning
> empty-handed to  the alien form.
>
> There was one last shudder of tension, and then she relaxed completely. **Flat like gold coins, the luminous eyes gazed back at her.**
> Tentative  tendrils extended to touch her fingertips. They began to
> move as the alien  body began to sway.

and at the end he takes her dog, Diamond.

> Diamond glanced one last time back at the couch and its silent, peaceful occupant. Then he turned as though responding to an unvoiced call
> and followed the visitor out into the rain, along the path that led
> through  the forest to the beach.

You can read the entire story online [here](https://archive.org/stream/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v074n04_1988-04_AK/Fantasy__Science_Fiction_v074n04_1988-04_AK_djvu.txt), in a copyright friendly format.